# How to spawn a mob that takes extra knockback regardless the weapon used?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I am planning to do a manhunt with lots of things as twists (Video title would be:"Minecraft Manhunt but Buttons, Pressure plates, and Trapdoors are OP) so if you hold a blackstone button, it would spawn a piglin that takes extra knockback, targets the other player by using the Brain angry_at nbt tag, and never turns into a zombified piglin. I don't want my friend to be absolutely overwhelmed by the piglins, because it would be too unfair (even though I know the twist and he doesn't). So, I was thinking, if the piglins took about 5 times the knockback, it would be a lot fairer when I get a headstart on the twist.

So, basically, how to spawn a piglin that takes more knockback no matter the weapon used?

Comment: can anyone pleeaaasseee answer?

Comment: Which server are you using i.e. vanilla/bukkit/spigot/forge ?

Comment: vanilla, but it is fine to throw a little plugin because I am open to change my server type. No mods, though, please.

Comment: I found a few plugins but they are for older versions of mc, If you are wiling to spend money (most probably you wont) then  go to https://www.spigotmc.org/resources/knockbackmaster-%E2%AD%90-professional-custom-knockback-and-hits-for-pvp.42721/

Comment: PLEASE ANSWER ANYONE PLEASE